# Normal force from a table on a fixed wedge with a mass sliding down?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

How would you calculate the normal force from a table on an inclined fixed wedge with a mass sliding down?
Let's say the wedge has a mass M and incline angle theta. The block is sliding down with a mass m. The wedge is fixed, meaning it doesn't move. What is the normal force from the table on the wedge?

Answer (score 0):

"Normal" means perpendicular here. The normal force the table exerts on the wedge is a force perpendicular to the surfaces in contact. This is not necessarily the total force. There can be a component parallel to the surface.

Normal force often comes up for a particular kind of force. A table is a rigid object. If you push on one atom of the table, that atom pushes on all the other atoms of the table just hard enough that the table keeps the same shape. The reaction force means the table pushed back with the same force. The table pushes back just hard enough to keep the wedge from penetrating into the surface.

This force that keeps the table rigid is perpendicular to the surface. If there is a force parallel to the surface, that is friction - a different kind of force. Think of rigid ice. You slip along the surface, but you don't penetrate. Think of concrete. You don't slip because of friction.

In the case of the wedge, perhaps it doesn't slip because of friction Perhaps because of glue. Either way that is a different force than the normal force. The normal force is vertical in this case.

You might consider all the forces on the wedge. The wedge is fixed. What does that tell you about the total force? Can you use that to calculate the normal force?

Answer (score 0):

Since the wedge is fixed we know that the next force acting on the wedge must be zero. That means the sum of the vertical forces acting down on the wedge equals the upward normal force $N$ on the wedge.

There are two forces acting down on the wedge, the force of gravity $Mg$ and the downward vertical component of the contact force between the sliding mass and the wedge. To determine the latter, unless the contact surfaces are frictionless, you will need to know the coefficient of kinetic friction.

> If they are frictionless, is it enough to take the cosine of the
> normal force between wedge and block? This would give the vertical
> force on the wedge due to the block right?

That would be correct and can be shown by a free body diagram on the wedge for no friction between the block and the wedge, as shown in FIG 1 below. In this case the normal force $N_T$ exerted by the table on the wedge is

$$N_{T}=(M+m\cos^{2}\theta)g$$

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Perfect explanation, appreciate it

Comment: @WilliamHarvey So is my answer acceptable to  you?